# Why do I get an ValueError for an SVR model with RFE, but only when using pipeline?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, svr, rfe

I am running five different regression models to find the best predicting model for one variable. I am using a Leave-One-Out approach and using RFE to find the best predicting features.

Four of the five models are running fine, but I am running into issues with the SVR. This is my code below:

```
from numpy import absolute, mean, std
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# one hot encoding
dataset.Gender.replace(to_replace=['M','F'],value=[1,0],inplace=True)

# select predictors and dependent 
X = dataset.iloc[:,12:]
y = dataset.iloc[:,2]

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

First I run LOOCV with all features, this runs fine

```
## LOOCV with all features
# find number of samples
n = X.shape[0]
# create loocv procedure
cv = LeaveOneOut()
# create model
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
# evaluate model
scores = cross_val_score(regressor, X, y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=n)
# force positive
#scores = absolute(scores)

# report performance
print('MSE: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
```

Next, I want to include RFECV to find the best predicting features for the model, this runs fine for my other regression models.

This is the part of the code where I get the error:

```
# automatically select the number of features with RFE

# create pipeline
rfe = RFECV(estimator=SVR(kernel = 'rbf'))
model = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('s',rfe),('m',model)])
# find number of samples
n = X.shape[0]
# create loocv procedure
cv = LeaveOneOut()
# evaluate model
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=n)
# report performance
print('MSE: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
```

The errors I receive are

```
ValueError: when `importance_getter=='auto'`, the underlying estimator SVR should have `coef_` or `feature_importances_` attribute. Either pass a fitted estimator to feature selector or call fit before calling transform.
```

I am not sure what this error means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RFE` operates by fitting its estimator and then eliminating the worst feature(s), and recursing.  The "worst" feature(s) are determined by using feature importance from the model, by default using either `coef_` or `feature_importances_` (as noted in the error message).  `SVR` has no such attribute, and indeed does not really come with builtin feature importances, especially with a nonlinear kernel.  See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/265656/232706

With the estimator being a pipeline, you'd anyway need to give more detail to the `RFE` on where to get the coefficients, see the second paragraph of [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) for `importance_getter`:

> Also accepts a string that specifies an attribute name/path for extracting feature importance (implemented with `attrgetter`). For example, give `regressor_.coef_` in case of `TransformedTargetRegressor` or `named_steps.clf.feature_importances_` in case of `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` with its last step named `clf`.

Finally, if you really want to use `SVR`, have a look at the third paragraph of the docs for `importance_getter`:

> If callable, overrides the default feature importance getter. The callable is passed with the fitted estimator and it should return importance for each feature.

<s>You can write a callable that uses, say, permutation importance (though this will be expensive) or some other agnostic importance measure.</s> *Erm, actually, since the callable only gets the fitted estimator, and not the data, permutation importance won't work.*  See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/191402/232706